# Make label aligned to custom checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Followup to this question [Make custom checkbox label text row breaks like normal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64221260/make-custom-checkbox-label-text-row-breaks-like-normal/64224425).

I have a custom checkbox and I want to make the label text align with the checkbox `span` element.

I tried a few thing but nothing seems to move anything. How can thi be solved?

```css
      input[type="checkbox"].custom-switch {
        display: none;
      }

     .switch{
    display: inline-flex;
  }

  .switch:before {
    width: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #EEE;
    content: "";
    margin-right: 5px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
  }
  
  .switch:after {
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    content: "";
    transition: margin 0.1s linear;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #aaa;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
  }

  input[type="checkbox"].custom-switch + label {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  input[type="checkbox"].custom-switch:checked + label > .switch:before {
    background-color: #1a94ff;
  }
  
  input[type="checkbox"].custom-switch:checked +  label >.switch:after {
    margin: 2px 0 0 17px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input class="custom-switch" id="updateAllCheckbox" type="checkbox" style="top: 2px;">
  <label for="updateAllCheckbox" style="font-weight: normal; font-family: inherit;">
    <span class="switch"></span>
    Some text about updating
    <select class="form-control dropdownUpdate" style="width: 90px; display: initial; padding: 0px; height: 23px; margin-right: 3px;;margin-left: 5px;">
    <option value="red">Newest Ver</option>
    <option value="yellow">Old Version</option>
    <option value="green">Outdated Ver</option>
  </select>
  Even more text to format
  </label>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div>
  <input class="custom-switch" id="test3" type="checkbox" style="top: 2px;">
  <label for="test3" style="font-weight: normal; font-family: inherit;">
    <span class="switch"></span>
    Checkbox with custom switch without a select element
  </label>
</div>
```

---

Update:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean vertical align.

How about:

```
label {
   /* replaces existing display: inline-block (i.e. 
      remove it from the inline style or replace it) */
   display: inline-flex; 
   align-items: center;
}
```

(By the way: I've learned this by playing https://flexboxfroggy.com/ . It's totally worth the time!)

Comment: exactly how i would do it too, but i think bootstrap has set label to inline-block and it wont let it get overwritten which makes things complicated here. Atleast im trying to get that working for 10 minutes now in a Snippet and it always stays inline-block

Comment: So the inline style is applied by bootstrap using JavaScript? Otherwise the OP can just use the `display:inline-flex` in the inline style maybe.

Comment: that would defiently work but it looks so "unclean" if you know what i mean :D mixing inline-style and Stylesheet. Thats why im trying to get a solution without this, but yes thats a way to do it

Comment: When doing it, the text wraping gets broken like in my previous question I linked at the beginning. I like that the checkbox is now infront of the text all times but if there is only one word after the select element and the space gets to small, the test before the select gets wraped into a new line but not the text after the select or the select element itself

Comment: Here is an image how I want it to be: https://i.imgur.com/4RSazux.png

Comment: Ok it is simple. When just wrapping the text content in a div then the text gets wrapped the rigth way.

Comment: @sirzento didn't know that this would work, thanks for sharing! Btw, another - maybe hacky - way to do it would have been to just add `vertical-align: -2px` to `.switch`.